# How to let two bodies collide in Farseer and pass the impulse to the 2nd body?

Tags: box2d, farseer

I have a sandbox with a puck (circular fixture) and a bat (directed by user's mouse movements). If the user hits the puck I want it to get an impulse based on the mouse movement speed.
However I have issues:

- In the collision delegate if I check the linear speed of the bat it is either 0|0 or something completely random (it seems).
- If I just give a constant impulse to the puck, the movement speed of the bat is not included.
- I want to apply the impulse at the contact point of the two bodies and not to the center of the puck. Is there a way to access the coordinates of that point if the collision occurs?

What is the correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by looking at the XNA Samples of Farseer.
You'll have to create a Joint, to be more specific, a FixedMouseJoint:

```
oPlayerJoint = new FixedMouseJoint( this.oPlayerBat, this.oPlayerBat.Position )
{
  MaxForce = 1000f * this.oPlayerBat.Mass
};
this.oWorld.AddJoint( this.oPlayerJoint );
```

Then when updating the game logic, something like this:

```
MouseState oMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
Vector2 oMousePos = new Vector2(oMouseState.X - GAMEFIELD_WIDTH / 2f, oMouseState.Y - GAMEFIELD_HEIGHT / 2f);
// Make the bat follow the mouse.
this.oPlayerJoint.WorldAnchorB = oMousePos.ToPhysicsUnits();
```